# Convert existing iphone4 application into both iphone4 and iphone5 using storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

i made an application for iphone4 using storyboard. Now i want to make it compatible with both iphone4 and iphone5. how can i do that. 
By using xib. i know how to load xib seperately for iphone4 and iphone5.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] resolution] == 3)
{
    nibNameOrNil=@"AddTextViewController iPhone5";
}
else
{
    nibNameOrNil=@"AddTextViewController";
}
```

But using storyboards, what should i do to achieve my goal. Thanks in advance

Comment: Interface Builder gives you options to do this. Constraints and autosizing are two offered features that are commonly used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

[ http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2] you should use auto layout to do that;

Comment: kindly give a comprehensive answer with advantages and disadvantages of using storyboard, autolayout.